# PHP documentation mouse-over JetBrains PHPStorm 3.0

Tags: php, phpstorm

Is it possible to set mouse-over view of method/class documentation in PHPStorm 3.0?

So if I start typing some method name, I see its autocompletion, but there is no PHP documentation anywhere?

```
/**
 * Some function.
 *
 * @param $status_code  Status code
 * @param null $message Message
 */
public function error($status_code, $message = NULL) {
    echo $status_code . " - " . $message;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried their support site? http://www.jetbrains.com/support/phpstorm/index.html . You're better off asking there

Comment: JetBrains support monitors its product tags and replies here as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible for explicit code completion:

[image: documentation]

However, [documentation on hover is not supported yet](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-5999).

Comment: Yeah, I got that but I though it's available throgh mouse-hover. Thanks.

Comment: eclipse has... I'm tryin to switch on phpstorm, but still dont' understand all those delights around it :)

Answer (score 13):

I know the title says **3.0**, but for anybody looking for this question on `PHPStorm 7` you can do this by going to `File > Settings`, under **IDE Settings** go to `Editor`. And then in the **right pane**, scroll down to the **"Other"** sub section, and mark **Show quick doc on mouse move**

Comment: +1. This should be a in seperate question for 7.0, almost overlooked it.

Comment: and for phpstorm 2019... `Setings > Editor > General > [Show quick documentation on mouse move]`